# how can I turn the content of the span into a php variable / How do I start a mysql query when clicking a word and send that word to _post in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, global-variables

I am building a dictionary and I have my words and definitions stored in a MySQL database.
I want to make some words clickable (maybe as spans or buttons) so when I click them a new query that has this word as key starts (so how can I send the content of this clicked word into to _post in my details.php file)? Or how can I turn the content of the span into a php variable?

```
<html>
    Click this <button>word</button>
</html>

<?php 
    
    echo "You clicked that " $word;
    
?>
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript/Jquery and add eventlistener to the word and request content with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL communicates with your server-side code (PHP).

Your PHP code reads/writes data into MySQL, generates (or loads) HTML templates that are sent to the browser when requested.

Your browser requests a page via URL when someone visits your site, sending a request to your URL and getting some response, presumably HTML in return.

From the moment when the page is received, CSS rules are being applied with design purpose and programmatic code (Javascript) is being executed.

Now, your `span` is part of your HTML, which was either received from the server, or generated by your client-side code (Javascript).

It is important to note that in production mode the browser and the PHP code are running on different, remote computers and sometimes the MySQL RDBMS is also running on a separate computer, a database server.

So, the thing you want to do is to have a Javascript event that sends some content to your server, which processes it and then stores it into your MySQL database.

## Event creation via Javascript

Read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Basically you will need to create an event, which will either be an

```
onclick="yourJavascript()"
```

or a call to `addEventListener`. Try to implement a trivial example for that, like below:

```js
    document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("Yay! The click was handled!");
    });
```

```html
    <input type="button" value="click me" id="mybutton">
```

Later on you will need to replace the function body with a request sending.

## Send an AJAX post request and receive a callback

Read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Read this article as well: https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest

Example:

```
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", URL, somedata);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 3) {
            // loading
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // request finished
        }
    };
```

It is worth converting something similar to a parameterizable function so in the future you would be able to reuse most of the benefits of your current work. And call this function I just suggested in your event listener.

Explanation:

- `XMLHttpRequest` is the type you instantiate in order to send an AJAX request
- `xhr` is the resulting object of the instantiation
- `xhr.open` is a function that you need to call, passing the request method (which is `"POST"` in this case, the URL, which is the target and some data)
- `somedata` is a variable the code above assumes that was already defined, but you will need to properly initialize it yourself
- `send` is sending the request, in our case asynchronously, that is, the request will not end yet when the next line is processed
- `xhr.onreadystatechange` is a [callback](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp) which is executed when the ready state changes; state 3 is loading, state 4 is request finished, so your meaningful code should be inside the `if` that checks for the state being 4

## Handle POST requests with PHP

Read this article: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/php+handle+post+request

Basically you will have your data in `$_POST`, you can process whatever logic you want and you can generate an HTML/JSON/whatever response the way you like.

## PHP - MySQL

You can generate MySQL queries with PHP and you can use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), for example, to generate parameterized queries and sanitize your dynamic parameters, especially those defined by the users, to avoid [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: @Kena you are welcome! Please let me know if you have questions, I will be happy to provide more information. Also, if this answer leads you to a solution, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Because I already had my input/submit search form ready, I solved it this way, but all that I read from your suggestions led me to this simple solution.  Thank you a lot!  
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#related_word_1', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#related_word_1").click();
    $("#search").click();
    $("#submit").click();
}); 
</script>
<a class="shembujt" id="related_word_1" ><?php if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $row['related_word_1'])){echo "<br>", nl2br(($row['related_word_1']));}?></a>